Solaris 11 cbe: no more updates?
Oracle release 11.4 cbe some years ago, to give Solaris free for non commercial use.
I was happy about this, but..
root@solaris2:~# LANG=C pkg publisher
PUBLISHER                   TYPE     STATUS P LOCATION
solaris                     origin   online F http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/
root@solaris2:~# LANG=C pkg update
No updates available for this image.
Planning linked: 1/1 done

As you can see this version don't get any update since 2023
pkg history|grep install
2023-02-22T18:39:25      uninstall                transfer module    Riuscito
2023-03-28T00:19:38      install                  pkg                Riuscito

Is my fault?
I've set publisher with this command
pkg set-publisher -G'*' -g http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release/ solaris

As you know a system without updates is not safe to use..
As I know Solaris use two repositories: release and support, the support repository is only for subscribers with a support contract, so they release Oracle for free use and.. no updates?
pkg info entire report
 Version: 11.4 (Oracle Solaris 11.4.42.111.0)


From the output of pkg info entire, you have Solaris CBE (Common Build Enviroment).
The CBE is just for users who want to use Solaris without paying for it. That way, one can determine if it is viable for production use and then purchase a subscription if that is the case. If you want an OS that functions in the same way, then just use OpenIndiana which is effectively Solaris with updates and security and bug fixes at no charge. The same is true of Rocky Linux and Alma Linux which do the same if one doesn't want to pay for a subscription for Red Hat Enterprise Linux. One can get a free developer subscription with RHEL and access the repos for updates and patches for free but beyond that, one has to have a paid subscription hence the requirement for production whereas that isn't required to have a subscription at all regardless of anything else for updates and patches with Rocky or Alma.
Once you have OpenIndiana, you can keep Solaris if you want but you really won't need it anymore especially considering that it won't receive updates and security patches.

Oracle intends to release periodic updates to the CBE releases, we can't commit to when the next one will be but work in that direction is happening as there are changes in Solaris such as moving to OpenSSL 3 which are important to make available to developers.

Is really "strange" solution imho, I remind in the old good times Hp-ux and Solaris and Aix, release the iso for free, and also the patches, if you want support by telephone you will pay (and is right) then all forbid to download the iso, and the patches became only for people with contract support. RHEL take a good decision they give a "developer way" for free, including the patches. Is one of the reason because Linux getting strong and used, and Unix is practically die.

A os without updates is in the modern time, not usable. Is ok only on protected network, without internet access (sic) if possible.
